# Tutorials for Unit-Testing in WordPress and for unit-test.svn.wordpress.org?

Tags: debug, testing

I'm starting to learn [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/) and I am interested in implementing what I've learned in my WordPress projects. I've seen http://unit-test.svn.wordpress.org and wonder if there are any tutorials or core-developer's notes on how to use it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Resources on how to use the WordPress unit-test:**

1. [WordPress Automated Tests Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/tests)
2. Automated Testing in The [Codex](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/automated-testing/)
3. The Unit-Test [README](http://unit-test.svn.wordpress.org/README.txt) File (broken)
4. The PHPUnit [Manual](https://phpunit.de/documentation.html)
5. Hakre/WP Unit-Tests [Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/User:Hakre/WP_Unit-Tests)
6. [Block Unit Test for Gutemberg](https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-unit-test/)
7. [Unit Tests for WordPress Plugins](https://pippinsplugins.com/series/unit-tests-wordpress-plugins/)

Comment: Another nice answer.

Comment: @btw, i got this information from hakre blog.