# How to perform unit testing on proposed patches in Trac?

Tags: taxonomy, debug, testing, patch

I was looking for some insight and good resources on how to correctly perform unit testing on proposed WordPress patches in the Trac and how to accurately report the results from the testing. I'm new to this and have read through the resources located in this [WPSE question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/703/tutorials-for-unit-testing-in-wordpress-and-for-unit-test-svn-wordpress-org).

I myself would really like to learn how to do this and do so with a real-world bug, like this Trac ticket [#5809](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5809). I guess after reading through the resources in the previously mentioned WPSE question my short coming is that I do not understand how I would setup the proposed testing for the proposed patch.

**Update:** I'm still searching for resources and currently watching this video on [WordPress unit-testing](http://wordpress.tv/2011/08/20/nikolay-bachiyski-unit-testing-will-change-your-life/).

Comment: Please come back and answer your own question here once you've resolved it.  I would really like to how to do it too.  As would, apparently, three others who upvoted the question.  Thanks.

Comment: @marfarma If I end up answering my own question I will certainly do so with detail. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @hsatterwhite Any progress?

Comment: @kaiser, None as of yet. Got side tracked on this one, but hopefully getting back to it this week as time permits. I'll be sure to update this with anything I find/figure out/etc.

Answer (score 2):

I really found this presentation from WCSF to be extremely helpful. http://wordpress.tv/2011/08/20/nikolay-bachiyski-unit-testing-will-change-your-life/

Comment: Just saw your update... :)

Comment: No worries! I appreciate the help with resources. Haven't really had a chance to get to this msyelf due to time constraints, but I really want to.