# PHP unit testing WordPress?

Tags: php, theme-development, testing

Given how WordPress is written and how it interacts with a database and given how its not very much OOP oriented, is there a way to unit test a theme? is there a way unit test a framework (not a theme framework) that interacts with WordPress, that is, for example, can you write a unit test for dealing with the loop, dealing with the widgets?

If so does any one have any examples? I know how to write unit tests, but I have never tried to write one for a theme.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from writing your own unit testing for themes/plugins using PHPUnit or some other testing platform.

As for WordPress, it has an official  Unit Tests here:

- http://unit-tests.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/
- https://github.com/kurtpayne/wordpress-unit-tests (github mirror)

There are several [build scripts](http://wpgear.org/) that can automate unit testing found here, including WP-CLI that have built in unit testing, though you have to obviously write your own code.

I also found this plugin today via scibu's twitter rant :)
 http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/razor/
There are a few more in the repo:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/phpunit

**Also check out this**: [Tutorials for Unit-Testing in WordPress and for unit-test.svn.wordpress.org?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/703/tutorials-for-unit-testing-in-wordpress-and-for-unit-test-svn-wordpress-org?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote the Travis-CI powered PHPunit testing library for [Jigoshop](https://github.com/jigoshop/jigoshop) and [Easy Digital Downloads](https://github.com/pippinsplugins/Easy-Digital-Downloads) both of which are Ecommerce WP plugins developed on Github. The library employed could be easily converted to work for themes. The nice thing about the Travis-CI powered suite is that we can use it to quickly test multiple PHP and WP versions. If you're theme is a premium theme, and thus putting it on a free Github repo isn't an option, the suite works on Private Github repos with Travis-CI.

Alternatively, you can use the one found in Jigoshop and use commandline powered PHPUnit.